# Does マンション also mean "luxurious house" in Japanese?

Tags: loanwords

According to [Jisho.org/mansion](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3) and [Japanese Core 1000](https://iknow.jp/courses/566932) マンション in Japanese means "apartment, condominium, residential building". But in English where the word might come from, it also refers to a large block of flats in British English, but its primary meaning is "a large, impressive house", which is the meaning we use also in Spanish (we don't use the apartment or condominium meaning at all as far as I know). Therefore this "luxurious house" meaning seems to be missing in Japanese. Does マンション also mean "luxurious house" in Japanese?

Comment: Did you try looking at dictionaries in Japanese? Did you find any evidence of this meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the Japanese word マンション does not carry the same meaning as "mansion" in English.

Monolingual dictionaries will only list the meaning you mentioned, even though they may point out that the word has a different meaning in English. For example, the entry in 大辞林 reads

> **マンション** **【mansion】**〔大邸宅の意〕
>
> 中・高層の集合住宅。比較的規模の大きいものをいう。

using the word 大邸宅 "large residence" (or of course "mansion") in angled brackets to show that the English word has a different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

According to the dictionary マンション means only an apartment.
It does not have the same meaning as in English.
Even when you say 高級マンション, it still means an apartment and not a house.

> マンション(mansion)《大邸宅の意》中高層の集合住宅。ふつう、分譲形式のものをいう。

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210432/meaning/m1u/マンション/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210432/meaning/m1u/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3/)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/マンション/#je-72231](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3/#je-72231)