# Does プレゼント have both English meanings or just the "gift" meaning?

Tags: loanwords

Present in English means both gift, and it also mean the current (present) time. Japanese online examples and translation seem to omit this second meaning. Does プレゼント have both English meanings or just the "gift" meaning?

Comment: I thought you might have taken advice from [your question of two days ago](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61755/1628), where all comments/answers suggested to consult a dictionary for this type of question. Did you? If so, please include what you found in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Japanese プレゼント

Looking at various JA→EN dictionaries, the "gift" sense appears to be the only one in common usage.  Links:

- [Eijirō Online](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)
- [Weblio's copy of Kenkyusha's New J-to-E Dictionary (研究社 新和英中辞典)](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)
- [Jim Breen's WWWJDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MUJ%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)

Looking at monolingual JA↔JA dictionaries appears to corroborate this.  Links:

- [Kotobank's copies of Daijisen and Daijirin](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88-622279)
- [Japanese Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)

#### The other English senses

- For "present time": 現在【げんざい】, 今【いま】
- For "present, in attendance": 出席【しゅっせき】 (when describing people sitting, as at a meeting or movie or class), いる (when simply stating that someone **is**)

Answer (score -1):

I do not have any information about frequency of such usages, but according to [Japanese Wordnet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/cgi-bin/wn-gridx.cgi?usrname=&gridmode=wnja&lang=jpn&lang2=eng&lemma=%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88) it has both meanings as "gift" and as "present time".

Probably second meaning is less frequently used in everyday speech.